# Understanding a statement about composite linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra

I know the definition of a bijective linear map $L: V \rightarrow W$ (one that is both injective and surjective). However, my book states that it is equivalent to assert that its inverse $K: W \rightarrow V$ satisfies $K \circ L = Id_V$ and $L \circ K = Id_W$.

Why? This is given in my book completely out of the blue, so a hint/explanation in how to prove it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Let's show that $K \circ L = \text{Id}_{V}$ implies that $L$ is injective.

Let $v, u \in V$ be arbitrary and suppose that $L(v) = L(u)$. Applying $K$ to both sides, we see that

$$ (K \circ L)(u) = K(Lu) = K(Lv) = (K \circ L)(v).  $$

Now since $K \circ L = \text{Id}_{V}$, we see that

$$ u = (K \circ L)(u) = (K \circ L)(v) = v  $$

so $u = v$ and $L$ is injective.

QED.

Let's show that $L \circ K = \text{Id}_{W}$ implies that $L$ is surjective.

Let $w \in W$ be arbitrary. Now since $L \circ K = \text{Id}_{W}$, we see that $L(K(w)) = w$. Now notice that $K(w) \in V$. Setting $v = K(w)$, we conclude that there exists a $v$ in $V$ such that $L(v) = w$. Since $w$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $L$ is surjective.

QED.

Comment: The book may have glossed over this because this is a basic fact about maps between sets:  no linear algebra necessary.  They may have taken it as assumed knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show that a linear map $L: V \rightarrow W$ is bijective if and only if it is invertible. Invertible meaning that there exists some linear map $K: W \rightarrow V$ such that

$$ K \circ L = \text{id}_{V} $$
and

$$ L \circ K = \text{id}_{W} .$$

$(\Rightarrow)$ Suppose $L$ is a bijective linear map. It follows that $L$ has an inverse linear map (do you know why?). Furthermore, the inverse is unique so we denote it by $L^{-1}$. Then

$$ L^{-1} \circ L = \text{id}_{V} $$
and

$$ L \circ L^{-1} = \text{id}_{W} .$$

$(\Leftarrow)$ Now suppose that $L$ is an invertible linear map, so there exists some linear map $K: W \rightarrow V$ such that

$$(1) \hspace{0.5cm} K \circ L = \text{id}_{V} $$
and

$$(2) \hspace{0.5cm} L \circ K = \text{id}_{W} .$$

You can check that $(1)$ above implies that $L$ is injective and $(2)$ implies that $L$ is surjective, so $L$ must be a bijection.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! What I do not see is why the existence of the inverse linear map implies $K \circ L = \text{id}_{V}$ and $L \circ K = \text{id}_{W}$. I understand that the definitions of composite linear maps are $K \circ L: V \rightarrow V$ and $L \circ K: W \rightarrow W$

Comment: Ahhh I see it! It is because of the Identity transformation being $Id: V \rightarrow V: v \mapsto v$

Comment: That's the definition of inverse. We say that a map $K: W \rightarrow V$ is an inverse of $L: V \rightarrow W$ iff $K \circ L = \text{id}_{V}$ and $L \circ K = \text{id}_{W}$. We can then show that the inverse is, in fact, unique. If you have any other doubts please let me know so I can modify my answer.

Comment: Hi Kevin I've proven (please see my edit) that (1) and (2) imply that L is injective and surjective respectively. Do you see it OK?

Comment: Hi! I've read them and submitted an edit to make the arguments a little bit clearer. As @Randall pointed out in a comment above, this is a fact about functions rather than just linear maps. We only use linear algebra when we show (or when we assume) that $K$ and $L$ are linear.

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort! Just one more thing: would not be enough to state that 'as the inverse map of the injective map L is injective then L is surjective'?

Comment: Glad to help! Considering the equivalence above, if we begin with the hypothesis that a  map has an inverse, we then get that it is also bijective, so injective and surjective. Its inverse would also be a bijection, so the proposition you wrote would be true but somewhat redundant.

Comment: I really enjoyed the discussion! Hope to come across you again in the Linear Algebra tag!

Comment: I enjoyed it as well! Take care!